# nrepl inserting <newline> every 1024 characters

Tags: emacs, clojure, nrepl

I'm seeing a newline forcibly inserted in nrepl output roughly every 1024 characters.

This [commit](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/NREPL-18) looks like it's setting
`clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session/*out-limit*` to `1024`, but binding it
to a new value did not fix it.

This is reproducible for me from `emacs -Q` 24.3.1 on OSX.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A year late to the party, but inserting a newline has been fixed in cider https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/commit/0db3fe0db0e77443552c21d61938c7baebb2a581

I strongly suggest using cider (Emacs client for nrepl) as it offers more features than using nrepl out of the box.